# get element number from list

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list. Every element is a bunch of text to process. Think on the list as a book. Every element a page.

The final output of the process is a dataframe with some results from regular expressions for every list element.

I want the number of the element added to each row. Notice the empty element is disappeared. I've created a dummy function to ilustrate (the real process is more complex)

```
mylist <- list("some text here 234","","more text here 23 ","adding a bunch of words 98") 

getnumber <- function(text) {
  str_extract_all(text,pattern = "[0-9]+") 
  }

lapply(mylist,getnumber) %>%  unlist() %>%
  data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


    .
1 234
2  23
3  98
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
    .  element
1 234     1
2         2
3 23      3
4 98      4
```

Comment: Why not just `str_extract_all(unlist(mylist), "[0-9]+", simplify = TRUE)`? As a side note, there is absolutely no need to run loops on vectorized functions.

Comment: You are totally right @DavidArenburg, I should have noticed this in the first place. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `unlist` does only keep the `list`-Elements that are not emtpy. And as @DavidArenburg points out correctly we don't need the `lapply`:

```
data.frame(
  . = str_extract_all(unlist(mylist), "[0-9]+", simplify = TRUE),
  element = 1:length(mylist),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Output:

```
    . element
1 234       1
2           2
3  23       3
4  98       4
```

Comment: All of you are missing the point that the provided function is a dummy one. And sometimes there's more than one row/list element per page. The point is getting the page number not the other issues